# VS2008 Immediate Window Lost

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I work in Visual Studio 2008, and a moment ago, I lost access to the windows usually docked at the bottom of the IDE (Immediate, Error List, Search Results) and I can't find a way to get them back again.

I tried

- Using all the possible shortcuts (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>)- none of them work
- Using the menu: Debug > Windows > Immediate- did not work
- Doing a search- no results appear
- Rebooting- didn't work either

I can however watch, dock, and generally work the breakpoints window.
When I am in Debug mode I can see them again, but if I try to de-dock the window, I get a VS Exception.

Has anyone experienced this issue before?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The menu commands (which you've already tried)

- Debug > Windows > Immediate
- View > Find Results > Find Results

or the keyboard shortcuts

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> (For the Immediate window)

should work.

If they don't, (and it isn't because the windows are collapsed, undocked, etc) then something has gone wrong.

Try

```
Window > Reset Window Layout
```

(see Mladen's post) and if that fails, try restarting Visual Studio.

If all else fails, you can try

```
Tools > Import and Export Settings... > Reset all settings
```

(It gives you an option to backup your current settings)

Comment: @Daniel, How did you get those cool keyboard keys to display?

Comment: @Jhonny: Is the window undocked/hidden or something?

Comment: i think hidden, because I don't see it anywhere

Comment: Sometimes you need to make sure you're working in Debug mode too, not Release.

Answer (score 4):

Another one to try, While running the app, go to Window/Reset Window Layout...

Comment: Too late for trying, but tx anyway

Comment: No problem :) Just trying to help

Answer (score 0):

Try This

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2009/05/14/immediate-window-is-missing-in-visual-studio-menu.aspx

This is where you can find immediate window from command window