# Is the immediate window being phased out?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I lost this window, then found it again using [Ctl+Alt+I](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761750/vs2008-immediate-window-lost) but I can't see it in any of the menus in VS2010ultimate.

- Does this mean it's getting phased out?
- If so which tool should I be using to achieve similar results?
- If it isn't one of the default menus and you have to customise an out-of-the-box menu does that inicate it's being phased out?

[image]

some more proof of the lack of immediate window in my VS:

[image]

Comment: It is *not* being phased out, and it's definitely still available in VS 2010. You must have set up your environment with one of the pre-set configurations that doesn't include it. Tools -> Import and Export Settings... -> Reset All Settings. Then pick something like the C# settings, and your environment should return to normal.

Comment: I'll give this a go...WORKED!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have deleted the command from the toolbar. Go to **Tools**, **Customize**, Click on the **Commands** tab, then scroll down and click on **Debug**, then select **Add Command**. Then, scroll down and select **Debug** in the left hand side Categories menu, then scroll down and find **Immediate** :).

See here:

[image]

Comment: nope - doesn't work on mine! I'll add a picture to original post

Answer (score 2):

Weird, it's there for me in VS 2010 ultimate:

[image]

Comment: all I have is Breakpoints ! ...is it because I'm in a windows form project?

Comment: just added my own photo - not imagining it!

Comment: what size is that lovely font?

Answer (score 2):

On the Toolbar click: Debug -> Windows -> Immediate

Are you sure you're not looking under the Windows tab?

Edit:

http://www.vitalygorn.com/blog/post/2008/01/Missing-Immediate-Window-in-VS2008.aspx[image]

Comment: @whytheq - did you goto the customize step and add this command back into under the Debug tab?

Comment: see Cody Gray's comment - I used this and all ok now